# Joomla - much code generated with php => blank page

Tags: php, joomla

I use Jumi to unsert custom php to joomla articled.

```
function generateTR($tr_nr) {
    $html="";
    for ($i=0; $i<$tr_nr; $i++) {
        $m=memory_get_usage();
        $html.="<tr><td colspan='5'>$i - $m</td></tr>";
    }
    return $html;
}


echo "<table><tbody>".generateTR(20000)."</tbody></table>";
```

If I run this code (generateTR(20000)) through jumi => I get blank page.
And if I run it directly by accessing php file => it's displaying the table OK.

And if change number of rows to 2000 => generateTR(2000) => it will show OK the table inside the joomla article through jumi.

Why when I increase the amount of html code => joomla + jumi cannot handle it?
Also I tried sourcerer instead of jumi => same problem.

Is there any solution?

Thanks.

EDIT:
I tried to increase max_execution_time to 180 sec; and also memory_limit to 2000M

EDIT2:
No errors in logs...

with

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

got some errors but not related to that problem... because when with few tr rows the errors are the same and the table is displayed OK.

Comment: probably running up against an execution time limit or memory limit.

Comment: EDIT: I tried to increase max_execution_time to 180 sec; and also memory_limit to 2000M

Comment: Any errors in error log?

Comment: turn on display_errors and error_reporting. don't debug in the dark.

Comment: Marc: I tried error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); ini_set("display_errors", 1); but no related errors there.

Comment: @ihtus please change  `$html.="<tr><td colspan='5'>$i - $m</td></tr>";`  to  `echo "<tr><td colspan='5'>$i - $m</td></tr>"; flush();`

Comment: Hoang Giang: same problem...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The cause of the blank page is "System - SEF" plugin.
Here is the bug - http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=24865

You will get blank page in Joomla 1.5.

In Joomla 2.5 you will get "500 - PHP regular expression limit reached (pcre.backtrack_limit)"

This is same bug.

2 solutions:

1) disable "System - SEF" plugin, if you don't need SEF

2) if you need SEF -

add

```
ini_set('pcre.backtrack_limit',1000000);
```

or

```
ini_set('pcre.backtrack_limit',1000000);
ini_set('pcre.recursion_limit',1000000);
```

to index.php of your template.

Answer (score 0):

Add in the beginning

```
set_time_limit(0);
```